# Docker shared container within multiple docker compose projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` which get's 2 services up (I have left out all irrelevant data from it).

```
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    image: ...
    container_name: app-${ENV}
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - 80

  db:
    image: ...
    container_name: my-cool-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

The point to see here is that `app` is getting a container name depending on the parameter. So basically I have a shell script running the following:

```
ENV=$1 docker-compose -p $1 up -d
```

So in short, whatever I forward as parameter, the new app container should be brought up. For example if I do `sh initializer.sh first` I will get `app-first` container. `-p` parameter is specified so I can have multiple instances of same container classified as a different project.

If I have a single container this works great, and I end up with say:

```
app-first
app-second
app-third
```

What I would like to achieve is to have all containers use the same DB. But when I do a `docker-compose` my DB container still wants to be brought up independent of his existence already.

Is it an issue that it tries to create a DB under different project name, but with same container name so it causes the collision?

Can this be made without bringing up 2 separate DB containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky solution:

change your compose file to

```
services:
  app:
    image: ...
    container_name: app-${ENV}
    networks:
    - shared
    expose:
    - 80

  db:
    image: ...
    container_name: my-cool-db
    networks:
    - shared
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"

networks:
  shared:
    external: true
```

Then first create the network `docker network create shared`

Bring up db: `docker-compose up -d db`

First app: `ENV=first docker-compose -p first up -d app`

Second app: `ENV=second docker-compose -p second up -d app`